# Google CSE (Custom Search Engine) custom query parameter shows no result

Tags: google-analytics, google-custom-search

So I was trying to link Google CSE to Google Analytics. However, the "Search Terms" in the GA shows funny cache link. I actually expect the search queries by the users here.

[image]

According to [this StackExchange answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98195/google-analytics-site-search-returns-cache-in-search-term-results-why), it is because the cached results use the same query parameter used in CSE, which is `q`.

So I'm thinking of changing the query parameter of the CSE in the control panel. Note: I'm using the "Google hosted" layout.

[image]

This works, and now the CSE link uses `query` as the parameter instead of `q`. However, there is no result shown. It seems that search results only appear when the parameter is `q`.

[image]

Does anybody know how to make the results come up using custom query parameter name?

At the end of the day, I just want to get the search terms in my Google Analytics.

## Edit:

You can try this snippets with CSE that I set up for Reddit.
https://jsfiddle.net/kd4wjfeg/4/

Note that if you change the `query` to `q` in the URL, the results will show up. I've set up the CSE settings to use `query` as parameter name, as shown in screenshot above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the search box with the correct attribute:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes

For your example you need:

```
<div class="gcse-searchbox" queryParameterName="query">
```

Along with other attributes

Comment: That is at the Google Analytics side to monitor the traffic. My problem is when I change the CSE query parameter name, the search results no longer show up. Search results only show up if the query parameter name is "q".

Comment: It still doesn't show the results, though. Seems like the attribute will just override the CSE settings. For example, if I put "search" for the attribute, the URL now uses "search" as the query parameter name instead of "query" (which was set in CSE control panel). 

I've edited my questions and provided a snippet of the HTML which you can try.

Comment: I think it might have to do with you picked the Google hosted option that opens in a new window?